# Is it possible to communicate with an Android device acting as a Portable Wifi Hotspot?

Tags: android, wifi, android-wifi

I need to send/receive messages between two Android devices without a separate Wifi access point. If one of the two devices acts as a Portable Wifi Hotspot, is it possible for the other Android to share messages with it on connecting to it?
I am aware of WifiDirect, but I have the limitation of supporting at least Gingerbread devices.

Answer (score 0):

It should be, check the IP details on the client phone/tablet, the "gateway" or "dhcp server" is the IP of the one with the Hotspot on.